# Prove there is a two coloring of $K_n$ with at most ${n \choose a} 2 ^{1 - {a \choose 2}}$ monochromatic $K_a$

Tags: probability, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

A problem from Alon, N., & Spencer, J. H. (2015). The probabilistic method. John Wiley & Sons.

Outline suggested: Take a random  two-coloring. Let $X$ be the number of monochromatic $K_a$ and find $E[X]$. For some coloring the value of $X$ is at most this expectation.

My approach so far:

Make a random two-coloring (w.l.g red/blue) of $K_n$ with $p(e = blue) = 1/2$. Let $X_{ \left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{n}}$ be the indicator random variable that the subset of vertices $\left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{a}$ is a monochromatic $K_a$.

$$E[X_{ \left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{a}}] = P(X_{ \left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{a}}) = \frac{1}{2^a} \times P(\left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{a} = K_a) $$

if I am not mistaken $P(\left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{a} = K_a) = 1 $.

Let $X$ be the number of monochromatic $K_a$ in $G$ then:

$$E[X] = \sum_{\left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{a} \in V} E[X_{\left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{a}} ]= \sum_{ \left\{ V_i  \right\}_{i = 1}^{a} \in V} \frac{1}{2^a} = {n \choose a} \frac{1}{2^a}$$

Which is different from $ {n \choose a} 2 ^{1 -  {a \choose 2}}$. I suppose I have a mistake in the calculation of expectancy. I also don't know how to make the final conclusion:  For some coloring the value of $X$ is at most this expectation => there is a 2-coloring of $K_n$ with at most  ${n \choose a} 2 ^{1 -  {a \choose 2}}$ monochromatic $K_a$

Comment: Note that the probability of the subgraph being monochromatic is $\frac{1}{2^{a-1}}$ as the subgraph can be both red or blue, there are 2 possibilities.

Comment: Remember that you are coloring *edges* not vertices.  How many edges all have to be the same colour for the $K_a$ to be monochromatic?  BTW there seems to be a typo in the question, one of the $\binom{n}{a}$ should be a $\binom{a}{2}$.

Comment: Ah yes! you are both right! Thanks!

Comment: For the conclusions, given the calculated expectancy, we can say there is a 2-coloring with at most said number of monochromatic $K_a$ but also one with at least said number?